Efficient way to sum specific rows in a file
I wish to sum specific rows of a column based on the value of other columns.
e.g., example file (comma-separated):



Id
Date
Time
value




11001
20240901
01:00:00
0.5


11001
20240901
02:00:00
0.5


11001
20240901
03:00:00
0.8


11001
20240901
04:00:00
0.5


11001
20240901
05:00:00
0.0


11001
20240901
06:00:00
0.5


11001
20240901
07:00:00
0.2


11001
20240901
08:00:00
0.5


11001
20240901
09:00:00
0.1


11001
20240901
10:00:00
0.2


11001
20240901
11:00:00
0.2


11001
20240901
12:00:00
0.7


11002
20240901
01:00:00
0.1


11002
20240901
02:00:00
0.3


11002
20240901
03:00:00
0.1


11002
20240901
04:00:00
0.6


11002
20240901
05:00:00
0.9


11002
20240901
06:00:00
0.1


11002
20240901
07:00:00
0.15


11002
20240901
08:00:00
0.3


11002
20240901
09:00:00
0.2


11002
20240901
10:00:00
0.7


11002
20240901
11:00:00
0.5


11002
20240901
12:00:00
0.3



So separately for each ID, I want to sum the values from 01:00:00 - 06:00:00, 07:00:00 - 12:00:00, 13:00:00 - 18:00:00 and 19:00:00 - 00:00:00 (of the next day).
My final output with the example above should look as such:



Id
Date
Time
value




11001
20240901
06:00:00
2.8


11001
20240901
12:00:00
1.9


11002
20240901
06:00:00
2.1


11002
20240901
12:00:00
2.15



Note that the Time column here contains the ending time for each period.
Any advice on how to do this most efficiently? Thanks

Using python you should use the csv library to read in the csv, and then manipulate things from there. The official docs explain how to use the library fairly clearly.

What you show is not a file but the image of a spreadsheet. Could you show the raw content of the file? If as I assume the file is a csv file, you can easily read with the standard library csv module, or if you intend to do heavier computation you should considere using Pandas.

Are the entries for every ID/Time always present and ordered, or can it skip times for an ID or be out of order? What does the raw data look like? Is it tab delimited, comma delimited, other?

@SergeBallesta it's not an image but rather a table ('Edit' the question to see the content); if OP's file is tab-delimited then this table format is ideal as it allows us to cut-n-paste from the table into our environment as tab-delimited data

please update the question to show your awk coding attempt(s) and the (wrong) results generated by your code

please update the question's expected output; the sample input shows entries for 00:00:00 so those numbers should generate output entries for 20240831, right? also, verify that the Time column in the output is the ending time of a period; also, update the question with details on what to display if there are no sums for a given time period, eg, if there is no data for 13:00:00 - 18:00:00 then do we generate an output row of 18:00:00 / 0.00 or do we skip the output row (ie, do not print a for for 18:00:00)

update the question to insure the expected output matches the sample inputs; in the expected output this includes a) the missing entries for 20240831 / 00:00:00 and b) the missing values for 20240901 / 12:00:00

I updated the question, giving the full input file and the corresponding output. And yes, the Time column is always the ending of period,

@akann show us your efforts

@ouroboros1 why did you remove tags? OP is not looking for a python answer specifically

@Paolo: You're right, I suppose; I reset them. Though in the interest of increasing the acceptability of the question, I thought some focus is useful. I will re-add the clarification you just deleted though, because the OP just put that here in the comments. Given the "history" of this Q, it's not strange that it got closed, but I'd say that in its current form, there's not that much reason to keep it closed (apart from the lamentable lack of the OP's own attempt, but yeah).

the samples should include some data that spans 2 days (ie, data in the range 19:00:00 - 00:00:00); in particular, which day should be displayed? if you only have the entry 20240831 / 20:00:00 and we need to display as 20240901 / 00:00:00 then a solution needs the ability to perform date math to derive 20240901 from 20240831; likewise, if we only have 20240901 / 00:00:00 and we're to display 20240831 / 00:00:00 then, again, a solution will need the ability to perform date math to derive 20240831 from 20240901

@markp-fuso: agreed, such an instance would have been nice in the Q. I've added some rows to the df in my answer to show that pd.Grouper handles such a case correctly.

If your real input is comma-separated then show comma-separated input in your example, don't show a markdown table which we'd all then have to convert to CSV to test a potential solution with and we'd be guessing at whether fields are quoted or not, etc. If your real data can have multiple dates, then include multiple dates in your example, etc. Make it as easy as possible for as many people as possible to help you and that includes providing a [mcve] that includes truly representative sample input and output that we can just copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

I Would proceed as follows:
1. Create "Bins" so:
01:00:00 - 06:00:00 = Bin 1
07:00:00 - 12:00:00 = Bin 2
13:00:00 - 18:00:00 = Bin 3
19:00:00 - 23:59:59 = Bin 4
You can do this with the pandas cut module: Here
example code:
import pandas as pd
#Create Bins Variable 
    bins = [pd.to_datetime('06:00:00').time(), pd.to_datetime('12:00:00').time(),
            pd.to_datetime('18:00:00').time(), pd.to_datetime('23:59:59').time()]

#Define the labels for the bins
labels = ['Bin 1', 'Bin 2', 'Bin 3']

#Create bins
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['col_a'].dt.time, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)

2. Use the Group By function to sum by each bin
Again a pandas module can help here, simply group by the ID and bins column and sum the column of interest, then depending on how you want the resulting table to look like, you might have to take some extra steps.
example code:
grouped_df = df.groupby(['bins', 'Id'])['col_a'].sum().reset_index()

My step by step:
Step 1 and Starting Table
Step 2
Table after Step 2
Step 3

Here's one approach using pandas:

Use pd.read_csv with parse_dates to create Date_Time in datetime format:

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(CSV), parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])

df.head()

            Date_Time     Id  value
0 2024-09-01 01:00:00  11001    0.5
1 2024-09-01 02:00:00  11001    0.5
2 2024-09-01 03:00:00  11001    0.8
3 2024-09-01 04:00:00  11001    0.5
4 2024-09-01 05:00:00  11001    0.0


Use df.groupby with 'Id' + pd.Grouper and get groupby.sum:

out = (
    df.groupby(
        ['Id', pd.Grouper(
            key='Date_Time', freq='6H', 
            closed='right', label='right'
        )]
    )['value'].sum()
)

Output:
Id     Date_Time          
11001  2024-09-01 06:00:00    2.80
       2024-09-01 12:00:00    1.90
11002  2024-09-01 06:00:00    2.10
       2024-09-01 12:00:00    2.15
Name: value, dtype: float64


If you want the original Date and Time columns back, you could do something like this:
out = (
    df.groupby(
        ['Id', pd.Grouper(
            key='Date_Time', freq='6H', 
            closed='right', label='right'
        )],
        as_index=False
    )['value'].sum()
)

out[['Date', 'Time']] = (out.pop('Date_Time')
                         .dt.strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S')
                         .str.split(' ', expand=True)
                         )

out = out.loc[:, ['Id', 'Date', 'Time', 'value']]

Output:
      Id      Date      Time  value
0  11001  20240901  06:00:00   2.80
1  11001  20240901  12:00:00   1.90
2  11002  20240901  06:00:00   2.10
3  11002  20240901  12:00:00   2.15


Note, incidentally, that pd.Grouper will correctly handle range 19:00:00 - 00:00:00 (of the next day). E.g.:
# some values for range `19:00:00 - 00:00:00`
extra_data = [[pd.Timestamp('2024-09-01 22:00:00'),11001,1], 
              [pd.Timestamp('2024-09-01 23:00:00'),11001,2]]

# add to original `df`
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(extra_data, columns=df.columns)], 
               axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# applying `out = (df.groupby(...)['value'].sum())`
out

Id     Date_Time          
11001  2024-09-01 06:00:00    2.80
       2024-09-01 12:00:00    1.90
       2024-09-02 00:00:00    3.00 # next day
11002  2024-09-01 06:00:00    2.10
       2024-09-01 12:00:00    2.15
Name: value, dtype: float64


Data used
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

CSV = """Id,Date,Time,value
11001,20240901,01:00:00,0.5
11001,20240901,02:00:00,0.5
11001,20240901,03:00:00,0.8
11001,20240901,04:00:00,0.5
11001,20240901,05:00:00,0.0
11001,20240901,06:00:00,0.5
11001,20240901,07:00:00,0.2
11001,20240901,08:00:00,0.5
11001,20240901,09:00:00,0.1
11001,20240901,10:00:00,0.2
11001,20240901,11:00:00,0.2
11001,20240901,12:00:00,0.7
11002,20240901,01:00:00,0.1
11002,20240901,02:00:00,0.3
11002,20240901,03:00:00,0.1
11002,20240901,04:00:00,0.6
11002,20240901,05:00:00,0.9
11002,20240901,06:00:00,0.1
11002,20240901,07:00:00,0.15
11002,20240901,08:00:00,0.3
11002,20240901,09:00:00,0.2
11002,20240901,10:00:00,0.7
11002,20240901,11:00:00,0.5
11002,20240901,12:00:00,0.3"""


This is the wrong output. I would need it with the end of the time period, i.e. 20240901 06:00:00 instead of 20240901 00:00:00.

Thanks @akann. Fixed that with label='right'. See the update.
